# altbeacon reference application cannot find Beacons

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon, altbeacon

I am trying to use the AltBeacon/android-beacon-library. I started with the [reference app](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference). Followed all the instruction to setup the app, but it still cannot find any beacon around. I also tried the Locate app, it cannot find beacons neither. I don't think there is anything wrong with the RadBeacons, since I can configure them with the app on iPhone. The Android phone I tried are Moto X(Android 4.4.4) and Samsung S3(Android 4.4.2), installed apps on both phones, neither of them works. Looked into the log of the library, as follows:

```
09-10 15:46:02.571: D/BtGatt.btif(1990): btif_gattc_upstreams_evt: Event 4096
09-10 15:46:02.571: D/BtGatt.GattService(1990): onScanResult() - address=3D:AC:95:C9:1C:D5, rssi=-64
09-10 15:46:02.571: D/BeaconService(11355): got record
09-10 15:46:02.577: D/WifiStateMachine(924): handleMessage: X
09-10 15:46:02.577: D/BeaconParser(11355): This is not a matching Beacon advertisement.  (Was expecting be ac.  The bytes I see are: 0201061aff4c000215078701d2fa844b429c161417dabc159d00010001c20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Also tried to install other apps from Google Play, such as [iBeacon Finder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobisfera.prod.ibeaconfinder), they do find the beacon.
Are there any additional configuration needed for the app or the beacon?

Can anyone help me about this? Very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using a proprietary beacon type, which by default the library will not recognize.  Understand that in order to keep the library free of intellectual property, by default it will only detect beacons meeting the new [AltBeacon](http://altbeacon.org) specification.  We cannot pre-configure it to detect proprietary beacons.

You may easily configure the library to work with proprietary beacons, but you must add a line of configuration code yourself.  Read the documentation in the [BeaconParser](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/javadoc/org/altbeacon/beacon/BeaconParser.html) class for details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand that I must change beaconLayout for those beacons do not meet the AltBeacon specification. I am using the RadBeacon from Radius Networks. I believe the tag should meet the specification. Or maybe I am wrong?

Comment: As of September 2014, the RadBeacon Tag does not transmit an AltBeacon advertisement.

Comment: OK. This makes sense. I got these RadBeacon Tags this week. Thank you!